# ionic build android error not creating the apk file

Tags: android, cordova, ant, ionic-framework

When I ran the following command:

```
ionic build android
```

in the command prompt on my Windows 7 machine I get the following errors pop up:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:542: Unable to resolve project target 'android-21'

Total time: 1 second

C:\Users\<user name>\Hello_Android\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126

throw e;

Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "ant-debug -f "C:\Users\<user name>\Hello_Android\platforms\android\build.xml" -Dout.dir=ant-build -Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen"

ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

You may not have the required environment or OS to build the project

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
at ChildProcess.whenDone <C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23>
at ChildProcess.emit <events.js:110:17>
at maybeClose <child_process.js:1015:16>
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Could anybody help me please with this problem?

Comment: The error says you may not have the required environment. Have you properly installed the Android SDK?

Comment: Do you have android 21 sdk tools installed in your SDK??

Comment: Looking at the Android SDK Manager, what I have installed are: all of the components of Android 5.0.1 (API 21), Android SDK Tools (Revision 24.1.2), Android SDK Platform-tools (Revision 22), Android SDK Build-tools (Revision 22.0.1) and Android SDK Build-tools (Revision 21.1.2).

Comment: I think it has something to do with my Apache Ant installation. The reason why I come to this conclusion is because when I type the ant command into the command line it comes up with Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed error. Has this got something to do with it?